# Missing hardrive on 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am completely new to Ubuntu, and the only previous experience I have with linux is on Android. Today I installed 14.04 alongside Windows Vista since it's a shared computer and my brother is stubborn. After giving Ubuntu a once over I decided I loved it but soon noticed that I'm missing a hardrive, I have 120Gb Main boot which has Vista installed, A 20Gb and two other 80gb which I have stiped together for media and my Steam Library. So `C:` as boot, `D:` as spare where I have Ubuntu installed, and then I: as the striped media drive. (`I:`) is missing, all it will show me is `C:` and `D:`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or have some troubleshooting I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Windows is assigning D: to what you earlier know as I:, as Windows cannot work with Unix-Filesystems. You can change the assignment on your System-configuration of windows. But this is something for Superuser ;)

Comment: Windows sees the drive just fine, it's Ubuntu that isn't seeing it.